# How to use lodash unionBy in a for loop to pass arguments dynamically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am trying to merge unknown number of arrays that come from a server as a result of many concurrent requests. I also need to remove the duplicates. Each element in the arrays is a json object.

I discovered that lodash has this `unionBy` method that takes the arrays as arguments and I can also pass the `iteratee` such as `"x"` and remove the duplicates based on `"x"`. This is cool.

However, it looks like I have to manually pass the array arguments to `unionBy` to make it work, but the problem is that, first I don't know how many I'll get from the request, and second I may end up getting 50 or more arrays and obviously it's not they way it should work.

I am basically trying to do this, where `result` is the result of all the requests and is an array holding the responses of those requests:

```
for(let i = 0;  i < result.length; i++){
    final = _.unionBy(result[i].data.offers, result[i+1].data.offers, ... , "id");
}
```

Of course this is not how it works, and I am wondering if anyone knows how can I pass the arguments in a loop above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get all the values you want and then use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to pass them to `unionBy`.

```
_.unionBy(...result.map(x => x.data.offers), "id");
```

Comment: awesome, exactly what I needed, thank you

Comment: @Suren No problem.

Comment: @Suren If this solved your issue, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.